# Why is the plot of NIntegrate is dirty (but it is correct)?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am trying to plot a numerical integral, it is correct but the plot is so ugly, how can I get a clean plot?

I couldnt evaluate it from zero to infinity thats another issue, but it evaluates between these limits it works for me but the plot is not beautiful.

Also I tried some internet solutions for oscillatory integrals, this is a plot of gaussian function, altough I dont know what it is, it didnt work.

I did try recursion, method etc but no luck
can anyone show me the way?

```
ClearAll[]
xforinstnc = 0.564*10^(-6);
k0 = 2*\[Pi]/xforinstnc;
yforinstnc = 532*2*\[Pi]*10^(12);
domeg0 = 53.2*2*\[Pi]*10^(12);
c = 3*10^(8);
zforinstnc = 50/k0;
aforinstnc = 20/k0;
bforinstnc = 20/k0;
M1 = 2;
Ix = 0.7;
Iy = 0.7;
funcnn = 1/(1 + (4*(omeg - yforinstnc)^2/domeg0^2));
Ax = Ix*funcnn;
Ay = Iy*funcnn;
Bxx = 1;
Byy = 1;
R0 = 25*10^(-6);
lambda11 = 0.0617167*10^(-6);
omeg11 = 2*\[Pi]*c/lambda11;
lambda12 = 0.1270814*10^(-6);
omeg12 = 2*\[Pi]*c/lambda12;
lambda13 = 9.896161*10^(-6);
omeg13 = 2*\[Pi]*c/lambda13;
lambda21 = 0.0617167*10^(-6);
omeg21 = 2*\[Pi]*c/lambda21;
lambda22 = 0.1162414*10^(-6);
omeg22 = 2*\[Pi]*c/lambda22;
lambda23 = 9.896161*10^(-6);
omeg23 = 2*\[Pi]*c/lambda23;
B11 = 0.7136824;
B12 = 0.4254807;
B13 = 0.8964226;
B21 = 0.6961663;
B22 = 0.4079426;
B23 = 0.8974794;
x = 0;
y = 0;
cforinstnc = 0;
funcnnmmn = 
1 + B11*omeg11^2/(omeg11^2 - omeg^2) + 
B12*omeg12^2/(omeg12^2 - omeg^2) + B13*omeg13^2/(omeg13^2 - omeg^2);
funcnnmmn2 = 
1 + B21*omeg21^2/(omeg21^2 - omeg^2) + 
B22*omeg22^2/(omeg22^2 - omeg^2) + B23*omeg23^2/(omeg23^2 - omeg^2);
funcnnmmn3 = 1/R0*Sqrt[1 - funcnnmmn2/funcnnmmn];
A = Cos[funcnnmmn3*z];
B = Sin[funcnnmmn3*z]/(Sqrt[funcnnmmn]*funcnnmmn3);
funcnnmmn4 = 
A^2 + B^2/((4*zforinstnc^4*k0^2)*(1 + 
4*zforinstnc^2/(m*aforinstnc^2)));
funcnnmmn5 = 
A^2 + B^2/((4*zforinstnc^4*k0^2)*(1 + 
4*zforinstnc^2/(m*bforinstnc^2)));

funcnnmmn6 = 
Ax*Ax*Bxx/(Sum[(-1)^(m - 1)/M1*Binomial[M1, m], {m, 1, M1}])*
Sum[(-1)^(m - 1)/M1*Binomial[M1, m]*1/funcnnmmn4*
Exp[-cforinstnc^2/(2*zforinstnc^2*funcnnmmn4)], {m, 1, M1}];

funcnnmmn7 = 
Ay*Ay*Byy/(Sum[(-1)^(m - 1)/M1*Binomial[M1, m], {m, 1, M1}])*
Sum[(-1)^(m - 1)/M1*Binomial[M1, m]*1/funcnnmmn5*
Exp[-cforinstnc^2/(2*zforinstnc^2*funcnnmmn5)], {m, 1, M1}];
funcnnmmn10 = funcnnmmn6 + funcnnmmn7;

funcnnmmn11 = 
NIntegrate[
omeg*funcnnmmn10, {omeg, 0.0000001, 532*2*\[Pi]*10^(13)}]/
NIntegrate[funcnnmmn10, {omeg, 0.00000001, 532*2*\[Pi]*10^(13)}]/
yforinstnc - 1;

Plot[{funcnnmmn11}, {z, 0, 0.002}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: bad plot]

Comment: Maybe you need to increase the `WorkingPrecision` value in `NIntegrate`...Try to `Rationalize` your numbers...

Comment: For 15-20 minutes the code before the `NIntegrate` call did not produce any results. If possible provide the explicit definition of your integrand. (Or a link to some file with it...)

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas : I did try WorkingPrecision, it tried to help but it didnt. I am now looking for Rationalize, since there are lots of numbers I need to rationalize all numbers you know...so still no luck

Comment: @AntonAntonov : I am new into this, so I didnt understand your statements. The integrand is   zero to infinity integral of omega*function / zero to infinity integral of function.  The function is a multi gaussian.

Comment: @srknski "I am new into this, so I didnt understand your statements." -- Evaluate `omeg*funcnnmmn10` and `funcnnmmn10` and post the outputs

Comment: @AntonAntonov     this is  Evaluate[funcnnmmn10]  for omeg = 532*2*\[Pi]*10^(12)    :                                                                             
 1.96 (1./(Cos[5429.01 z]^2 + 0.00298851 Sin[5429.01 z]^2) - 0.5/(
   Cos[5429.01 z]^2 + 0.00575565 Sin[5429.01 z]^2))

Comment: @AntonAntonov and this is  Evaluate[omeg*funcnnmmn10]  for omeg = 532*2*\[Pi]*10^(12)   :                                                                                                                        6.5516*10^15 (1./(Cos[5429.01 z]^2 + 0.00298851 Sin[5429.01 z]^2) - 
   0.5/(Cos[5429.01 z]^2 + 0.00575565 Sin[5429.01 z]^2))                                  is  it because the second one is 10^15 bigger than the first?

Comment: Hey look who is here :) @JoséAntonioDíazNavas  ,Once I cited your paper in my paper ''Crystalline human eye lens’ response to stochastic light''  Hope to work with you...thanks by the way for your help trial

Comment: Oh, Yes !!?, difficult to figure out by your username. Do not hesitate to contact me at at your convenience. ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have tried a workaround. I have rationalised your numbers and sampled $z$ and, then, plotted the points:

```
pts = ParallelTable[{i, 
Evaluate@((NIntegrate[
       omeg*newf10 /. z -> i, {omeg, 0, 532*2*\[Pi]*10^(13)}, 
       Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 4000}, 
       MaxRecursion -> 2000]/
      NIntegrate[newf10 /. z -> i, {omeg, 0, 532*2*\[Pi]*10^(13)},
        Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 4000},
        MaxRecursion -> 2000]/yforinstnc - 1))}, {i, 0, 0.002, 
0.000025}];

ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 2, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

It seems that those weird points are avoided. However, be advised that numerical problems with your `funcnnmmn11` definition exist. Maybe some kind of units normalization or a change in wavelength units could help to avoid calculations with high numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear friend @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, you solve the issue. And also when we increase the integration limit (and remove the pi) it becomes even better. Best wishes in your studies, hope to see you again...

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help and contribute :))